# Trigger an email in Python if SQL Query returns results

Tags: python, sql

I've connected a SQL query to Python and am trying to automate an email with attachment if the SQL query returns results. This query will show the discrepancies between our prices and the prices our client is selling our products at.

If there are differences between the 'Unit Price' and 'Selling Price', I want to email these to my director. However, if there are no differences, then the query will return 0 results and I do not want an empty email to be sent out.

My difficulty in this is that the python script is sending the attachment even if the query is returning no results. **I only want to send the attachment if my query is returning results**.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('''
SELECT SaleH.[Order No], SaleH.[Reference], SaleL.[Product code], SaleL.[Description], SaleL.[Quantity], SaleL.[Unit Price], SaleP.[Unit Price] AS 'Selling Price'
FROM [Sales Header] SaleH
INNER JOIN [Sales Line] SaleL ON SaleH.[Order No] = SaleL.[Order No] 
LEFT JOIN [Sales Price] SaleP ON SaleP.[Product Code] = SaleL.[Product Code] AND SaleH.[Customer No] = SaleP.[Customer No]
WHERE SaleH.[Customer No] = 'Cust01' AND SaleH.[Date] >DATEADD(DD,-1,getdate()) AND SaleP.[Unit     Price] != SaleL.[Unit Price]
''' ,conn) 
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_csv (r'G:\Customer Folder\Customer_Sales_Orders.csv', index = False) 
outlook = win32. Dispatch('outlook.application')
email = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail_from = "Sender"
mail_to = "Recipient"
mail_subject = "Customer Sales Orders"            
mail_attachment = 'Customer_Sales_Orders.csv'
mail_attachment_name = "Customer_Sales_Orders" +'.csv'
```

Comment: You say you have found no solutions but you haven't stated what the actual problem is. Is your difficulty being able to send an email with a CSV attachment or is it something else?

Comment: Hi @Booboo thanks for your message. Apologies I didn't make myself clear. My difficulty is sending the email attachment ONLY IF my query is returning results. Currently, the python script is sending emails even if there are no results. I need to find a way to implement a condition for this.

Comment: First, `sql_query`, which is the result from executing a call to `pd.read_sql_query` is already a dataframe and so there is no point in doing `df.DataFrame(sql_query)` If no rows are returned then `len(sql_query)` will be 0. Also, `sql_query.shape[0]` will be 0 as will `sql_query.count()[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
results = pd.read_csv('Data.csv') # count no. of lines
if len(results))> 0:
    #sendemail
    from_address = "<from which email>>"
  to_address = "<<to which email>>"
 
 # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
  msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
  msg['Subject'] = "Customer ha made purchases in the last 24 hours for  
  {}".format(date.today())
  msg['From'] = from_address
  msg['To'] = to_address
  
  # Create the message (HTML).
  html = """\
  This is an automated email.
  
  We are sending an email using Python and Gmail, how fun! We can fill this with html, and gmail supports a decent range of css style attributes too - https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css#example.
   """
  
   # Record the MIME type - text/html.
  part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
  
   # Attach parts into message container
  msg.attach(part1)
  
   # Credentials
  username = '<your email id>'  
  password = '<google_app_password>'
  
   # Sending the email
   ## note - this smtp config worked for me, I found it googling around, you may have to tweak the # (587) to get yours to work
  server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
  server.ehlo()
  server.starttls()
  server.login(username,password)  
  server.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())  
  server.quit()
```

Comment: You might also want to consider port 465 instead of 587 for Gmail. It is already encrypted so you do not need starttls()